# MahApps ShowMessageAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps-metro

Имеется такой код (в упрощенном варианта)

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Пожалуйста подождите...", string.Empty);
    x.Maximum = 100;
    x.SetIndeterminate();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            x.SetProgress(i);
            x.SetMessage($"Осталось {100 - i}");

            if (i == 50)
            {
                <---- здесь нужно вывести сообщение (например, произошла какая-то ошибка)
            }

            // code
        }
    });

    await x.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

И в общем вопрос, как вывести ShowMessageAsync внутри await Task.Run, так чтобы оно работало подобно MessageBox.Show, т.е. чтобы Task ждал реакции пользователя на данное сообщение. Если просто вставить ShowMessageAsync будет вылет из программы, т.к. вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к MainWindow, а если обернуть в Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, то Task продолжает выполняться не дожидаясь ответа пользователя на ShowMessageAsync

Comment: А просто Dispatcher.Invoke не подходит? Dispatcher.BeginInvoke все таки тоже асинхронная операция

Comment: Нет, сообщение выводится, но все равно продолжается выполнение кода в FOR. А нужно, чтобы сработало подобно MessageBox, т.е остановился FOR

Comment: Хотя, если добавить .Wait() то все работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог такой код

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.ShowMessageAsync("", "")).Wait();
```

Comment: та ктоже можно Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => await this.ShowMessageAsync("", ""));